# How to increase time duration of taking a video of Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I would like to know how to increase time duration of taking a video of Android Studio? I developed application and would like to explain the function using the video but it's only 3 mins to take a video as default and it's not enough to me. please kindly advice me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android Studio's screen record and screen recording via command line using `adb` seems to have a maximum limit of three minutes.

Here is the [adb screen record documention](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord) which states **--time-limit    Sets the maximum recording time, in seconds. The default and maximum value is 180 (3 minutes).**

You might want to look at recording two separate videos, then putting them together in a Video Editing program.